# how to compile openvdb, and link with cmake

Tags: cmake

I want to use `cmake` to compile a project into `vcproject`. 
https://github.com/david-hahn/FractureBEM/tree/master/hyena, but it lacks some `openVDB` library.

I want to know how to compile it successfully.

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
HLIB_INC
   used as include directory in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
   used as include directory in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
   used as include directory in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
   used as include directory in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
   used as include directory in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
Halflib
    linked by target "FractureBEM" in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
    linked by target "SegmentVDB" in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
    linked by target "VisMesh" in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
OpenVDBinclude
   used as include directory in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
   used as include directory in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
   used as include directory in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
   used as include directory in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
   used as include directory in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
OpenVDBlib
    linked by target "FractureBEM" in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
    linked by target "SegmentVDB" in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
    linked by target "VisMesh" in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
tbblib
    linked by target "FractureBEM" in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
    linked by target "SegmentVDB" in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
    linked by target "VisMesh" in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
zlib
    linked by target "FractureBEM" in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
    linked by target "SegmentVDB" in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
    linked by target "VisMesh" in directory D:/Learn/FractureBEM-master
```

Comment: These `NOTFOUND` variables corresponds to libraries/headers, required by the project but missed on your system. You need to install them for build the project: `zlib`, `tbb`, `openVDB`, `Half`.

Comment: thanks. I should fill in the correct location of the libraries and include folder.

Answer (score 1):

I also compile this project , the same as you ,I also encountered the same problem previously ,but now it seems ok if you install necessary libs.  The cmake error means you need to install openvdb lib ,installation of  openvdb through this website https://github.com/rchoetzlein/win_openvdb will be ok. you can compile it successfully under vs 2015 on win10 ,I already get it done.And the below the openvdb lib ,you can find zlib tbb boost half lib within build directory,additionally ,you will also need to get hyena core master  source from original authors ,because the project only provides patch of core which lacks many headers, last ,you will also install eigen ,tclap lib ,wish you good luck!